# R how to make loop faster

Tags: r, performance, loops

I have a code like below that contains two loops. The code reads monthly streamflow data and makes it as multi-replicate. The loops are so slow. I was wondering if there is any alternative way to make it faster?

```
library(xlsx)
library(data.table)

  a <- read.xlsx("streamflow.xlsx",sheetName = "Sheet1", header = TRUE)
  b=matrix(nrow=129792,ncol=17)
  b= data.frame(b)
  i=0

  for (j in -11:1236)
  {
   for (k in 1:104)
   {
    i=i+1
    j=j+12
    j[j > 1248] <-j-1248
    b[i,] <-a[j,]
   }
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: I can only see 2 loops. And what is `data.table` doing ?

Comment: Can you `dput(head(b))` so we can see the data and what's going on in the loop? There's probably a way to vectorize it

Comment: Also, `dput(head(a))`. Help us help you by giving a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#5963610)

Comment: @Wen: won't actually help.

Comment: Thanks @csgroen. a is reading a monthly time series of streamflow data such as 
                             St1   St2   . . . 
        Aug 1913    1000 2000
       Sep 1913      4000 5000
             .
             .
             ,
and b is an empty matrix which will be filled with multi-replicate of streamflows data. I converted b t data frame because I had error in the loop with matrix format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is a proper translation of your double for-loop into vectorized code.  It should increase the speed dramatically.  Also, there is no need to declare `b` as a matrix and convert it to a data.frame, the values can just be obtained from `a`.

```
j_iter <- -11:1236
k_iter <- 1:104

k <- seq(12, length(k_iter) * 12, 12)
k <- rep(k, times=length(j_iter))

j <- rep(j_iter, each=length(k_iter))
j <- j + k
j[j > 1248] <- j[j > 1248] - 1248

b <- a[j,]
```

Comment: Thanks @dvantwisk. It seems it is working and it is very fast.